# worklight javascript file failed to render in worklight environment folder

Tags: environment, ibm-mobilefirst

I have recently updated Worklight Developer version to 5.0.6.20130311-0918-developer-edition
One project that was working fine on older version are failed to render IPAD environment(js files).

To prove it is no our side issue, I create a new worklight project and add IPAD environment.
 then add a javascript alert function inside ipad/js/Test.js file as below:

```
function wlEnvInit(){
alert("test");
wlCommonInit();
// Environment initialization code goes here
}
```

I was expecting the IPAD emulator to pop up an alert file, but it didn't.
any one knows the reason?

Comment: Using v5.0.6 I have created a new project and application, added the iPad (and others) environment and added an alert("test"); before wlCommonInit() in the iPad environment's .js file, built and deployed.  When previewing, I received in my browser a dialog with the text "test". Can not confirm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using v5.0.6 I have created a new project and application, added the iPad (and others) environment and added an alert("test"); before wlCommonInit() in the iPad environment's .js file, built and deployed. When previewing, I received in my browser a dialog with the text "test". Can not confirm.

Comment: Yes, the problem is gone. After I restart the eclipse on the next day..(how interesting it is that I did the same thing a couple of times before posting this question,)